# Custom allocator leaking memory

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, visual-studio-2012

So the implementation of my custom allocator has a base class with 2 static variables, one to track the instances of allocators and one is the memory-pool.

```
template <typename T>
class Allocator : public Base_Allocator
{

public:
  // Required types
  typedef T           value_type;
  typedef size_t      size_type;
  typedef ptrdiff_t   difference_type;
  typedef T*          pointer;
  typedef const T*    const_pointer;
  typedef T&          reference;
  typedef const T&    const_reference;

  template <typename U>
  struct rebind
  {
    typedef Allocator<U> other;
  };

  // Required Opeartions

  explicit Allocator(void) : Base_Allocator() 
  { 
  }
  ~Allocator(void) { }

  Allocator(const Allocator& a) : Base_Allocator()
  {

  } // copy constructor

  pointer address(reference value) const { return &value; }

  const_pointer address(const_reference value) const { return &value; }

  size_type max_size(void) const { size_type m = 4096; return m; }

  pointer allocate(size_type n) 
  {
    return static_cast<value_type*>( Base_Allocator::m_pMemMngr->Alloc( sizeof(value_type) * n) );
  }

  void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n) {
    Base_Allocator::m_pMemMngr->Free(p);
  }

  void construct(pointer p, const T& value) {
    new((T*)p) T(value);
  }

  void destroy(pointer p) { 
    p->~T();
  }

  bool operator == (const Allocator& right) const { return true; }

  bool operator != (const Allocator& right) const { return false; }

};
```

and here is the baseclass...

```
class Base_Allocator
{
public:
  static int m_icount;
  static MemoryManager* m_pMemMngr;  

public:
  Base_Allocator(void)
  {
    m_icount++;
    if(!m_pMemMngr)
    {
      NEW(m_pMemMngr);
      m_pMemMngr->Init();
    }

  }

  ~Base_Allocator(void)
  {
    m_icount--;
    if(m_icount<0)
    {
      SAFE_DELETE(m_pMemMngr);
    }
  }

};
```

Here is the definition of the static members

```
#include "Base.h"

int Base_Allocator::m_icount = 0;
MemoryManager* Base_Allocator::m_pMemMngr = nullptr;
```

my thing here is that the memory is never being released. I'm passing it to a forward_list and this forward list creates 3 allocators but it also deletes 3. That's the reason I have the base class only free the memory once it is less than 0. But things haven't really worked out too well. -1 is never reached so I'm never releasing the memory in the memorypools. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I removed the `MemoryPool..` parts from your code and it compiled fine with gcc-4.8. Maybe it is a VS issue. I am not sure since I didn't test the whole code. But you can give it a shot on a unix machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from **effective STL**

> Make your allocator a template, with the template parameter T representing the type of objects for which you are allocating memory.

Satisfied

> Provide the typedefs pointer and reference, but always have pointer be T* and reference be T&.

Satisfied

> Never give your allocators per-object state. In general, allocators should have no nonstatic data members.

Not Satisfied, you have private member in ur allocator!

> Remember that an allocator's allocate member functions are passed the
>   number of objects for which memory is required, not the number of
>   bytes needed. Also remember that these functions return T* pointers Ma
>   the pointer typedef), even though no T objects have yet been
>   constructed.

Satisfied

> Be sure to provide the nested rebind template on which standard
>   containers depend.

Satisfied

so remove ur private member...